# retrieve mongoDB driver db from mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am designing a module provides a constructor function that takes in a mongo db instance as its parameter. In my application I am trying to test this using mongoose. Since mongoose was built on mongoDB driver module, I am assuming that there is a way to retrieve the db driver object from the mongoose module.

I have a function that is failing but I am unsure to the reason why.

**Update**

Below is the code from my module

```
//authorizer.js
function Authorizer(mongoDBCon, userOptions){
    this.db = mongoDBCon;
    this.authorize = authorize;
    this.assignOwner = assignOwner;
    this.setUserPermission = setUserPermission;
    this.setRolePermission = setRolePermission;
    this.retrieveUserPermission = retrieveUserPermission;
    this.setRolePermission = setRolePermission;

    let defaultOptions = {
        unauthorizedHandler: (next)=>{
            let error = new Error('user has performed an unauthorized action');
            error.status = 401;
            next(error);
        },
        userAuthCollection: 'user_authorization',
        roleAuthCollection: 'role_authorization',

    }

    this.options = _.assign({},defaultOptions,userOptions);
}

function setRolePermission(role, resource, permissions) {
    let document = {
        role: role,
        resource: resource,
        permissions: permissions,
    };

    //add the document only if the role permission is not found
    let collection = this.db.collection(this.options.roleAuthCollection);
    collection.findOne(document)
        .then((result)=>console.log('in here')) //------> not printing :(
        .catch(e=>{console.log(e)});
}
```

It needs to be imported/required in another file to configure

```
//authorizerConfig
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Authorizer = require('util/authorization/authorization');

let authorizer = new Authorizer(mongoose.connection.db);

//set admin role permissions
authorizer.setRolePermission('admin', 'users', '*');
authorizer.setRolePermission('admin', 'postings', '*');

module.exports = authorizer;
```

file with connection to mongo

```
//app.js
// Set up and connect to MongoDB:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);//MONGODB_URI=localhost:27017/house_db
```

I now am not seeing a log that I was hoping to see in the `then()` method.

1. Is mongoose.connection.db equivalent to the db instance returned
   from MongoClient.connect ?
2. Doesn't mongoClient support promises?
3. Can you help solve my issue?

---

**Answer:**
@Neil Lunn has provided me with the answer. To sum up, mongoose.connection.db is equivalent to the db returned from MongoClient.connect. Also, I had an error because I was querying the db before it has established a connection.

Comment: But as far as i can see, how this constructor know what is this.db & find as its function. Post your complete code, how you are going to achieve it. And also it will be great, if you fully dependent on mongodb native module or go for mongoose.

Comment: @rxysm no need for that. Neil Lunn has answered my question. He seems to have understood my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoClient and the underlying node driver certainly supports promises. It will simply be that you are not referencing the correct "database object" by whatever method you are actually using.

As a demonstration:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/other',    // connect to one database namespace
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2))
}

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    const testDb = conn.db.db('test');  // For example,  get "test" as a sibling

    let result = await testDb.collection('test').find().toArray();
    log(result);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})();
```

So what you "should" be doing is getting hold of the ["connection"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection-js) object from the connection, and referencing the [`db`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-db) from that. It's likely you want the "sibling" `db` space of the current connection, and probably `"admin"` in your specific case for grabbing "authentication" details.

But here we employ the [`.db()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#db) method off of the [`Db` Object](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html) in order to access a "named sibling". This is notably **not** an async method, just like [`.collection()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#collection) is not async.

From there it's just a matter of implementing other methods native to the respective object from the core driver.

Comment: You totally understood my question! Let me go test this out. Thank you for the response

Comment: So I am slightly confused with what ` conn.db.db('test');` does. In your example above, your uri was set to 'mongodb://localhost/other'. So the database you are connecting to is called 'other'.  what is 'test' supposed to represent here? and what do you mean by sibling db space? Isnt that just another db in the mongo application?

Comment: @alaboudi The `"test"` represents "another database name". **All** MongoDB installations actually use `"test"` as the default namespace. The "sibling" as mentioned in the answer would be `"admin"` in your case.

Comment: so I have just tried your solution and I'm getting the exact same result. I tried taking away the `then()` and log the chain up to the find() function. In both cases I get a cursor being returned back. Where do I go from there

Comment: @alaboudi You don't actually include your code in your question. So without seeing the code I cannot tell you what is wrong with it. This code by example works. So if yours does not work then you are doing something different. If you cannot work out what is different then "post your code".

Comment: @alaboudi Looking at your question are you calling `.find().then()` or are you calling `.find().toArray().then()`? Because the native driver does **not** return an array like mongoose does. It returns a "cursor", which is why I use the `.toArray()` "cursor" method in the example.

Comment: you make a fair point. I have added more code to the question. Also thanks for the note on the toArray() part. But I seem to still be at a stand still since I cannot print somethings in my then() method. Also I really would like to thank you for your input. Much appreaciated

Comment: @alaboudi I don't see anything in your code where you actually make the connection. In fact it looks like you are just passing in `mongoose.connection.db` before any connection is made and that of course will not be defined. You can only access this "after" the connection has been established. Which is what I am doing and what you appear **not** to be doing.

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit. Just added it in.

Comment: @alaboudi Again you are sending the reference **before** you make the connection. You actually have to retrieve the "active connection". That is what you are not doing. Look at my listing again. It's pretty explicit.

Comment: What you said makes a lot of sense! I have been trying to find an event listener method from the mongo driver but I have been unsuccessful. I will try to looks this up. Thank you so much @Neil Lunn you are pointing to me the right direction every time.

Comment: I have decided to make my entire application wait for the connection before starting and the code worked. Thank you a lot Neil!

Answer (score 12):

Note that this seems to have changed at some point and in v5 I can access the db like this:

```
const res = await mongoose.connect(...);
const { db } = mongoose.connection;
const result = await db.collection('test').find().toArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [connection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-db) object to retrieve the MongoDB driver instance.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb', function (err){
    if (err) throw err;
    let db = mongoose.connection.db; // <-- This is your MongoDB driver instance.
});
```

Comment: mongoose.connection.db gives undefined

Comment: @user3003976 Make sure you use it after the connection has successfully been established.

Comment: for me it was: _const collection = __mongoose.connection.client__.db(dbName).collection(collectionName);_