# How to reuse MongoClient in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a NodeJS application which uses MongoDB native driver to perform database operations. I have already initialized MongoClient. I would like to implement new features using Mongoose. How I can make Mongoose instances use already initialized MongoDB client? I searched the docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html and I can't find anything saying about setting the client. I found only information about getting it. Is it possible at all?

Comment: How about using both like connect database with `native mongoDB driver` and `mongoose`. Then use whenever any of them is required.

Comment: so you want to use mongodb native driver and mongoose together?

Comment: do it other way round - let mongoose to instantiate the client, then use it.

Comment: @AlexBlex thanks, that is what I thought is only possible... I don't understand why mongoose (it is very new to me, I just started today) is built this way. It just mutates its library and instantiates MongoClient on its own... Alex, just post your answer, I don't think there is other way around.

Comment: Take a look at this post, it might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272404/retrieve-mongodb-driver-db-from-mongoose