# Mongoose model not ready sometimes

Tags: mongoose

I'm initializing my mongoose models in an async function that I call directly in the file like follows. My issue is that sometimes, when I start my server, it complains of CvData to be null.

```
let CvData, Subscriber, User, Account, Session;
// Function to establish MongoDB Atlas connection
async function connectToMongoDB() {
    try {
        if( !uri ) {
            throw new Error('Please add your MONGODB_URI to .env');
        }
        if( !env.MONGODB_DB_NAME ) {
            console.warn("Please add your MONGODB_DB_NAME to .env. Using ", dbName )
        }

        await mongoose.connect(uri, {
            dbName,
        });

        //to avoid error: OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite CvData model once compiled
        if( !mongoose.models.CvData ) {
            CvData = mongoose.model('CvData', cvDataSchema);
            Subscriber = mongoose.model('Subscriber', subscriberSchema);
            Account = mongoose.model('Account', accountsSchema);
            User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'users');
            Session = mongoose.model('Session', sessionSchema);
        }
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272404/retrieve-mongodb-driver-db-from-mongoose
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB database "', dbName, '" at ', uri);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to connect to MongoDB Atlas:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

await connectToMongoDB()

export {CvData, Subscriber, User, Account, Session}
```

I don't get any connection error or something, should I wait for the line

```
CvData = mongoose.model('CvData', cvDataSchema);
```

Comment: I don't see where you defined `uri`, Why do you wrap it in a function `connectToMongoDB`?

Comment: The uri is get from env, it didn't seem relevant to mention how I initialize it. And the function is to describe what it does (by its name)

Comment: When I use mongoose usually the connect function only does `mongoose.connect`. In the index file I import the connect file. I use `mongoose.model` in the file that schema is defined so `export default mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)`.

Comment: That's just code styling, it couldn't explain the bug I think

Comment: Do you see any message logged? I think you can move the model init to outside the function because mongoose buffer operation until connected.

Comment: Showed this is happening after hot code replace

Comment: What message is logged?

Comment: method find not found in underfined, I removed the condition if( !mongoose.models.CvData ) and now it sometimes complains about model changing after initialization, but it's less often

Comment: Can you try to change the file to [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGdB2w)